# Executing wget command 404 Not Found error is being thorwn

Tags: wget

when i execute wget command below exception is being thrown. ANy suggestions?

```
command:
 wget --user 'myusername' --password 'mypassword' -r -A '*.jpg' 'http://123.12.12.123:8090/file/settings'


exception:
--2021-04-18 20:17:46-- http://123.12.12.123:8090/file/settings

Connecting to 123.12.12.123:8090... connected.

Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found

2021-04-18 20:17:46 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: So it says that the server is responded with 404 error. You should look to the server console to find the issue of that.

Comment: for curl, there no issue. however, curl unable to perform recursive .. Therefore, i was intending to use wget

Comment: Edit your question to precise that you expect to get jpg through recursion with wget.